# Scroll to top of MAUI ListView Header

Tags: listview, maui

I would like to add a "Back to Top" button to my ListView.  I can use the `ScrollTo()` function on the ListView to scroll to an item (ie. first item), but I cannot seem to scroll to the top of the ListView.Header; or top of the ContentPage - preferable.

I use a Grid to position the button at the bottom right of the screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage ... Title="Index">

    <Grid x:Name="gridMain">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="lvItems" VerticalOptions="Fill" 
                  BackgroundColor="White" 
                  SelectionMode="None" CachingStrategy="RetainElement" 
                  SeparatorVisibility="None"
                  HasUnevenRows="True" IsVisible="True">

            <ListView.Header>
                <VerticalStackLayout x:Name="vslListViewHeader">
                    ...
                </VerticalStackLayout>
            </ListView.Header>

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        ...
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

            <ListView.Footer>
                <VerticalStackLayout>
                    ...
                </VerticalStackLayout>
            </ListView.Footer>

        </ListView>

        <ImageButton Grid.Row="0" Source="arrow_up.png" 
                     HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="End" 
                     Padding="10" Margin="8" x:Name="imgbtnTop" 
                     Clicked="imgbtnTop_Clicked"></ImageButton>

    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

Code behind:

```
private void imgbtnTop_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // items ref: ObservableCollection used as ListView ItemsSource
    lvItems.ScrollTo(items.FirstOrDefault(), ScrollToPosition.Start, true);
}
```

If there is another way to do this (ex. using Navigation or similar), that would be fine too.  Also, I believe I read that this functionality will be available in v8.0.0, but I cannot find reference to that thread at this time.

Comment: Sometimes `CollectionView.ItemsUpdatingScrollMode` `KeepItemsInView` works.

Comment: @StephenQuan ListView doesn't seem to have that option.  Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the `ScrollToPosition` of method [ListView.ScrollTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.listview.scrollto?view=net-maui-7.0) to `ScrollToPosition.End`.

Based on your code,I created a demo and achieved this function.
You need to add two rows for your `ListView` and `Button` in the Grid.

Please refer to the following code:

```
<Grid x:Name="gridMain" > 
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListView x:Name="listView" Grid.Row="1"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Animals}"
         IsGroupingEnabled="True"
         Scrolled="OnListViewScrolled">

        <ListView.Header>
            <VerticalStackLayout BackgroundColor="LightGray"  >
                <Label Margin="10"   
               Text="Header" VerticalOptions="Center"
               FontSize="12"
               FontAttributes="Bold" />
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </ListView.Header>
        <ListView.Footer>
            <VerticalStackLayout BackgroundColor="LightGray">
                <Label Margin="10"
               Text="Footer"
               FontSize="12"
               FontAttributes="Bold" />
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </ListView.Footer>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid Padding="10">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                          Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" 
                          Aspect="AspectFill"
                          HeightRequest="60" 
                          WidthRequest="60" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" 
                          Text="{Binding Name}" 
                          FontAttributes="Bold" />
                        <Label Grid.Row="1"
                          Grid.Column="1" 
                          Text="{Binding Location}"
                          FontAttributes="Italic" 
                          VerticalOptions="End" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

    <Button Grid.Row="0" 
                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"   Text="Scroll"
                 Padding="2" Margin="8" x:Name="imgbtnTop" 
                 Clicked="OnButtonClicked"></Button>

</Grid>
```

Method `OnButtonClicked`

```
void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    GroupedAnimalsViewModel viewModel = BindingContext as GroupedAnimalsViewModel;
    AnimalGroup group = viewModel.Animals.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == "Bears");
    Animal monkey = group.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "American Black Bear");
    listView.ScrollTo(monkey, group, ScrollToPosition.End, true);
}
```

And the result is as follows:

[image]

**Note:**

1.The first screenshot is the initial state, and the second is the effect after clicking the button.
The `ScrollToPosition.End` member indicates that the item should be scrolled to the end of the view. In general, the Header will be displayed normally.

2.I tested on the official sample : [ListViewDemos](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/7.0/UserInterface/Views/ListViewDemos). And I replaced the sample code [ScrollByItemWithGroupingPage.xaml](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/blob/main/7.0/UserInterface/Views/ListViewDemos/ListViewDemos/Views/ScrollByItemWithGroupingPage.xaml) and [ScrollByItemWithGroupingPage.xaml.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/blob/main/7.0/UserInterface/Views/ListViewDemos/ListViewDemos/Views/ScrollByItemWithGroupingPage.xaml.cs) with the code I shared above.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I am trying to have the Back to Top button go to the top of `<ListView.Header>` in my example code.  Your response doesn't include that section of the ListView.  Furthermore, the `ScrollToPosition.End` only achieves scrolling to the bottom of the object listed as the first param of `listView.ScrollTo(object, ...)`

Comment: Sorry, I missed some of the code. And I have updated it.

Comment: Hi @iaps, please check my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to use custom renderers in your MAUI app.

The idea is to subclass `ListView` and add a public `ScrollToTop` method which invokes an internal `ScrollToTopRequestedEvent` when called. I then subclassed the `ListViewRenderer` on each platform and registered for the event.

The steps are as follows:

1.create a custom ListView(`MyListView.cs`) in folder `Controls` of your current app,and add an `EventHandler` for it.

```
public class MyListView:ListView 
{
    public event EventHandler EventScrollToTop;

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void ScrollToTop(bool animate = true)
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    {
        //bool animate is not used at this stage, it's always animated.
        EventScrollToTop?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

2.On android, create custom renderer(`MyListViewRenderer.cs`) on folder `Platforms/Android/Renderers`

```
namespace ListViewDemos.Platforms.Android.Renderers 
{
    public class MyListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
    {
        public MyListViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);


            var view = (MyListView)Element;
            if (view == null) return;

            view.EventScrollToTop += OnScrollToTop;

        }

        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public async void OnScrollToTop(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        {
            Control.SmoothScrollToPositionFromTop(0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

3.On iOS, create custom renderer(`MyListViewRenderer.cs`) on folder `Platforms/iOS/Renderers` ,add call method `Control.ScrollRectToVisible(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, 1, 1), true);` .

```
namespace ListViewDemos.Platforms.iOS.Renderers 
{
    public class MyListViewRenderer: ListViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            var view = (MyListView)Element;
            if (view == null) return;

            view.EventScrollToTop += OnScrollToTop;
        }

        public async void OnScrollToTop(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            Control.ScrollRectToVisible(new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, 1, 1), true);
        }
    }
}
```

4.Register renderers on `MauiProgram.cs`

```
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp() 
      {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                  .UseMauiApp<App>()
                  .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                  {
                        fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                        fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                  })
                  .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
                  {
#if ANDROID
                handlers.AddHandler(typeof(MyListView), typeof(ListViewDemos.Platforms.Android.Renderers.MyListViewRenderer));
#elif IOS
                handlers.AddHandler(typeof(MyListView), typeof(ListViewDemos.Platforms.iOS.Renderers.MyListViewRenderer));
#endif

            });

            return builder.Build();
      }
```

5.Usage example:

```
   <Grid x:Name="gridMain" > 
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>

       <controls:MyListView x:Name="listView" Grid.Row="1"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Animals}"
            IsGroupingEnabled="True"
            Scrolled="OnListViewScrolled">

           <ListView.Header>
               <VerticalStackLayout BackgroundColor="LightGray"  >
                   <Label Margin="10"   
                  Text="Header" VerticalOptions="Center"
                  FontSize="12"
                  FontAttributes="Bold" />
               </VerticalStackLayout>
           </ListView.Header>
           <ListView.Footer>
               <VerticalStackLayout BackgroundColor="LightGray">
                   <Label Margin="10"
                  Text="Footer"
                  FontSize="12"
                  FontAttributes="Bold" />
               </VerticalStackLayout>
           </ListView.Footer>
           <ListView.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <ViewCell>
                       <Grid Padding="10">
                           <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                               <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                               <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                           </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                               <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                               <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                           </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                           <Image Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                             Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" 
                             Aspect="AspectFill"
                             HeightRequest="60" 
                             WidthRequest="60" />
                           <Label Grid.Column="1" 
                             Text="{Binding Name}" 
                             FontAttributes="Bold" />
                           <Label Grid.Row="1"
                             Grid.Column="1" 
                             Text="{Binding Location}"
                             FontAttributes="Italic" 
                             VerticalOptions="End" />
                       </Grid>
                   </ViewCell>
               </DataTemplate>
           </ListView.ItemTemplate>
       </controls:MyListView>

       <Button Grid.Row="0" 
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"   Text="Scroll"
                    Padding="2" Margin="8" x:Name="imgbtnTop" 
                    Clicked="OnButtonClicked"></Button>

   </Grid>
```

Note:

1.For more information, please check document: [Reuse custom renderers in .NET MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/custom-renderers) and [Handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/).

2.My app's name is `ListViewDemos`,please change it to yours on your side.

Comment: Hi @iaps, may I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.